# Fast Secure way to upload data into Amazon S3

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, udp

We want to upload data in a secure way from our datacentre, which is a bank to Amazon s3.
**Fast way** - Tsunami UDP (It seems that UDP protocols are much faster compared to tcp protocals like scp,ftp etc).
However, Tsunami UDP cant directly stream into s3, but I can across this post with 
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx20YXSQ49507II/Moving-Big-Data-Into-The-Cloud-with-ExpeDat-S3-Gateway.
This plugin seems to be able to do so.
**Any other recommendations here**

Secure  - 
Amazon Direct Connect might have added costs so not considering for the initial phase.
Amazon Import/Export - This might only be feasible for the first time upload.
**Any recommendations here to create a secure channel between aws and the datacentre**

Comment: @BMW Instead of encryption, i was looking for a secure network kinda answer. Not very good at networking, but is it possible to use https kinda of tunnel for udp transfers, so we were absolutely sure no one is able to tap into the channel in the middle.

Comment: HTTPS uses encryption. How about ExpeDat mentioned in the link? `[Tsunami UDP] doesn't support native encryption` however later it says `ExpeDat, by Data Expedition Inc., addresses these shortfalls.`.

Comment: @prog_guy, think about Openvpn + GPG, it is cheap (open source) with no cost and fast. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN, support udp

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers, which is not the kind of question Stack Overflow is intended to address.  You seem to be solving a non-problem, given that S3 natively supports HTTPS *and* parallel multipart uploads, which remove any real or imaginary advantage UDP transfers might provide over TCP.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : It was stated that "upload/download your data to Amazon S3 via SSL-encrypted endpoints. " So does this mean, if I use the aws cli or multipart-upload, the data is encrypted before going into the internel channel (tcp) and unencrypted before it is stored into S3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to upload files directly to S3 from data source location you can go for [EvaporateJS](https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS). It also provide good security.